# What is styled.div``

Tags: syntax, styled-components, template-literals

In libraries such as styled components, there syntax to write CSS is as such.

```
cons styledButton = styled.button`put css here`.
```

I would like understand why/how is it possible to do that, to have a template literal right next to the property 'button'. Is it the same as

```
cons styledButton = styled.button(() => return `put CSS here`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `myFunction()` is not exactly the same, but similar to calling ``` myFunction`` ```. They're called [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). Test it in your console right now with any basic function. They'll both call the function but behave a bit different depending on the function.

> If there is an expression preceding the template literal, this is called a tagged template. In that case, the tag expression (usually a function) gets called with the template literal, which you can then manipulate before outputting.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals